# Checking URL for URL contains string to change Jade theme in express

Tags: javascript, regex, express, pug

I am trying to see how can I check if an URL string is present in an express application so that I can trigger a theme change.

Right now I have a simple router.get

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  res.render('index', { title: 'Home' });
});
```

What id like to do is to be able to check the url for a certain string. example  "Toy" and based on that trigger somehow jade/pug to display a different graphic from that.

```
store.org 
trigger main Graphic

toystore.org
trigger a different graphic
```

Then somehow pass this so that I can change the theme in pug/jade.  Thoughts?

I was thinking to simple do a string.match and look for that in a regex but that wouldn't work because I need to be able to manipulate this trigger to change the Them in pug/jade

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify a view based on some conditions of the request, you can do it like this:

- Check the condition in a middleware and add a custom property to the request or response object
- Use it later

In `app.js` above the routes:

```
const checkTheme = (req, res, next) => {
    if(req.hostname === "store.org" {
        res.locals.theme = "graphic"
    } else {
        res.locals.theme = "other-graphic"
    }
    next();
};

app.use(checkTheme);
```

Then just check the value of res.locals.theme where you need it.

EDIT:
Answering your additional question about "displaying different graphic" is difficult without knowing exactly what you mean.

If you want to display a page with totally different elements, you should create 2 pages and choose which one to render in your controller:

```
const getIndexBasedOnUrl = (req, res, next) => {
    if(res.locals.theme === 'graphic') {
        res.render('index/graphic');
    } else {
        res.render('index/other-graphic');
    }
};
```

If you want only minor changes, just check the value inside your view and use `if` condition to make changes

```
if theme === 'graphic'
    h2.green Description
else 
    h2.red Description
```

You can even use conditionals to import different css files.

Comment: @OLIVER Thank you, using pug/jade, how can I condition to display a certain graphic based on the URL?